# Не получается проверить пользователя в базе данных

Tags: c#, mysql, база-данных

Здраствуйте, при попытке подвязать базу данных к проекту получается ошибка, скриншот ошибки внизу.

```
private void buttonLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String loginUser = this.textBox1.Text;
            String passUser = this.textBox2.Text;

            DataBase dataBase = new DataBase();

            DataTable table = new DataTable();

            MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();

            MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM `users` WHERE `login` = @uL AND `pass` = @uP", dataBase.GetConnection());

            command.Parameters.Add("@uL", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = loginUser;
            command.Parameters.Add("@uP", MySqlDbType.VarChar).Value = passUser;

            adapter.SelectCommand = command;
            adapter.Fill(table);

            if(table.Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Succes");
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Disconnected");
            }
        }
Вторая часть:
class DataBase
    {
        MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection("server=localhost;port=3306;username=root;password=root;database=test_database");

        public void openConnection()
        {
            if(connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                connection.Open();
            }
        }
        public void closeConnection()
        {
            if (connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection.Close();
            }
        }

        public MySqlConnection GetConnection()
        {
            return connection;
        }
    }
```

К сожалению, разобраться сам не смог.

[image: Скриншот ошибки:]

Comment: Проект какого типа: .NET Framework или .NET Core? Возможно, версия провайдера mysql несовместима.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov кажется, что .NET Framework. А что в таких случаях можно сделать? Вполне, возможно, что и синтаксисе где-то ошибся. Вы беглым взглядом ничего критичного для работы программы не нашли?

Comment: Ну посмотреть в свойствах проекта. / Установите провайдер нужной версии.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov я посмотрел сейчас, все таки стоит .NET Core 3.1, не подскажите как можно установить провайдер другой версии? Не имею представления даже что это.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Необходимо было докачать пакет Nuget в Visual Studio для корректной работы класса.

Comment: Пожалуйста оставляйте более развернутые ответы, которые помогут понять, в чем была проблема другим посетителям StackOverflow. К сожалению, пока данный овтет понятен только вам.